# ionic 2: Zoom in ionic slides

Tags: ionic2, ion-slides

I am developing a project for e-commerce, and in product-detail page,i have one slider with product images. in that user can zoom that image.

my html code

```
  <ion-slides pager="true" style="height:45%" zoom> <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of selProd.productImages"> <img src="{{slide.image}}"> </ion-slide> </ion-slides>
```

but when i try to zoom image by pinch or double tap. it gives me error:

```
swiper-zoom.js:364 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
    at toggleZoom (swiper-zoom.js:364)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

Adding class swiper-zoom-container with div tag in between img tag and ion-slide tag solved the issue.

Ex.:

```
<ion-slides pager="true" style="height:45%" zoom>
<ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of selProd.productImages">
  <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
    <img src="{{slide.image}}">
  </div>
</ion-slide>
```